# Is there a function in Go to print all the current member names and values of an object?

Tags: go

I'm looking for something like PHP's print_r or python's **dict**. Anybody know if this function exists, or its something that needs to be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package in go.
You can find solution to your problem in the following [article](http://cheesesun.blogspot.com/2009/12/reflection-package-in-go.html).

Answer (score 3):

For printing native go objects,  like maps, slices, and arrays, you can try:

```
fmt.Printf("%v", object)
```

However there isn't a general method to do it with user-defined struct types..

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", object)
```

That might give you something resembling what you want.

Comment: From Go's manual: `when printing structs, the plus flag (%+v) adds field names`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the package `dump`, which acts similar to PHP's `print_r` or `var_dump`.

The [sources are here](http://code.google.com/p/golang/source/browse/src/pkg/dump) and the [main project page is here](http://code.google.com/p/golang/).

Then just call `dump.Dump(yourObject)` or `dump.Fdump(file, yourObject)`